# R: boot.ci - does type="basic" provide the correct confidence interval end points?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, statistics-bootstrap

In short, my question is whether boot.ci returns the correct interval endpoints for type="basic".

I am computing confidence intervals based on the boot package, using boot and boot.ci. I noticed that some confidence intervals looked strange when I used the "basic" type for the boot.ci function. In contrast, "bca" or "perc" produced what I expected. My first guess would be that "basic" mixes something up when substracting lower / upper end points. 
But I might be wrong, e.g., missing some crucial difference between the types "basic" and "bca" that explain this behavior.

See, e.g., the following code example. For purpose of illustration I create some highly skewed random data. I try to compute confidence intervals for the median. What I would expect, is a confidence interval that is positive (because the data is). What I get (see the first plot, based on type="basic") is a lower end point that is strongly negative, and the interval is skewed in the wrong direction. The second plot (based on type="bca") shows pretty much what I expect to happen if everything works correctly.

```
require(boot)
set.seed(1)
x <- 10^runif(100,0,5)-1 #sample data
medw <- function(x,i){ #statistic for bootstrap
    mm <- median(x[i])
}
resb <- boot(x,medw,R=1000) #bootstrap
ci <- boot.ci(resb,0.95,type = "basic") #confidence
require(plotrix) #for plotting
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plotCI(ci$t0,li=ci$basic[4],ui=ci$basic[5]) #confidence plot
boxplot(x) #boxplot, just for some visual context
```

[image: "basic" confidence interval (left) via boot.ci + boxplot (right)]

```
ci <- boot.ci(resb,0.95,type = "bca") #confidence
plotCI(ci$t0,li=ci$bca[4],ui=ci$bca[5]) #confidence plot BCA
boxplot(x) #boxplot, just for some visual context
```

[image: "bca" confidence interval (left) via boot.ci + boxplot (right)]

Comment: Did you check against the formula referenced in the help page?

Comment: I guess you mean Chap. 5 in Davison, A.C. and Hinkley, D.V. (1997)? I do not have acces to that book right now.

Comment: Can you explain what is your expected result, and how it deviates from it?

Comment: The expected result would be close to lower plot in the example I posted. The upper plots show a confidence interval that covers negative values (although the data is positive) and a skew in the wrong direction. I'll try to clarify this in the question.

Comment: I believe it's a quirk of your data being so heavily skewed; specifically you've hit a situation where the basic method fails. If I recall correctly from long ago in grad school, essentially the basic method is assuming that the quantile end points are well estimated by the bootstrap distribution itself, which in this case they are not.

Comment: Ok, I dug out my Davison & Hinkley and a better way to say this is that the basic method isn't using the raw bootstrap distribution quantiles; it's essentially using only bootstrap estimates of the bias & variance and assuming a normal approx in the process. If your bootstrap distribution is still highly skewed the basic method may do poorly, as it does here.

Comment: Is that not what type="normal" does? I guess I really have to order that book at some point.